# Wait in Loop until counter is decreased

Tags: node.js, wait, slot

I want to wait in a loop until a counter is decreased. Is this possible? At the moment, I think I need to wait x seconds and check the counter. Then check again. But is there a better solution?

So have a look what I mean:

```
counter=0;
for(x=1;x<100;x++){
 if(counter<10){
  counter++;
  dothings
 }else{
  wait until counter<10
  do things
 }
} 
function dothings(){
 calculate;
 counter--;
}
```

So only to show what I mean.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What are you actually trying to do.  Locking yourself in a loop until a condition is met is a good way to waste processing.  Why not be eventful and instead have something happen whenever a condition is met instead of continually checking if the condition is met so that you can do something?

Comment: I think you'd get better answers if you explained what you're doing a bit better.  It looks like you've abstracted your needs a bit too far from your original goals.  To me it looks like you're attempting to make your own que system, which there are several available.  If I'm correct check out kriskowal/q on github.

Comment: Is the intent of your pseudocode to have no more than 10 asynchronous operations in flight at a time?  Because, if so, there are many things about this code that need to be changed to get there.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and questions.
I load XML Informations (scores / schedules / standings) from a server. I pay for the service. But it's not possible to load all files at once. 
So my idea is to only load a fixed count of files, after the first is finished I could load the next.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the code style to event driven, use a method to decrement the counter and if the condition is met, call another method to 'do things'.